# What is a safer Linux installation mode: dualboot or virtual machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, dual-boot

Which Linux installation method on system running Windows 11 on bare metal (host OS) is safer?
(e.g. for online banking).

1. dual-boot
2. Windows 11 as the host and Linux in a Virtual Box.

- Dual-boot: is it possible that a virus, trojan etc. spreads from the host to the Linux dualboot system?
- Is it likely, that a infected host affects also the virtual machine?

Answer (score 3):

Neither one makes much difference, but the non-VM approach is marginally safer. The odds of any Windows malware seeking out and attacking a Linux installation on the same machine are extremely low, *BUT* if it happened then neither one is intrinsically harder to attack than the other unless you're using Secure Boot on the Linux system and the attacker can't bypass it.

The only differences are:

1. There are more ways to attack a VM (modify the virtual disk, modify the VM software, install a driver that monitors/modifies physical RAM while the VM runs, lift the whole system into a hypervisor and monitor it that way) than a bare metal install (modify the install partition, lift the whole system into a hypervisor). Modifying the Linux installation (in virtual or physical partition) is by far the easiest in either case though.
2. The risks can be partially mitigated using full volume encryption on the Linux partition(s). That rules out "modify the installation" in both cases, but does not rule out anything that involves running the Linux system in a VM/hypervisor, and it's simpler to do that if it's *already* running in one that you just have to suborn.
3. If you're using full volume encryption on Linux *and* you have Secure Boot enabled on Linux, then the attacker can't lift the Linux system into a VM or modify it without having a Secure Boot bypass, whereas even if you use full volume encryption + Secure Boot on Windows, once the malware is running (in the Windows environment) it could attack any VM running within Windows or within a hypervisor the Windows system controls.

---

Caveat: the safety of both systems depends almost entirely on how you use them and what you install. Linux is not inherently safe against malware, and although less malware is written for it, it's often a juicier target because it's used on lots of valuable systems like servers and tech company development/build machines. A Windows machine behind a firewall, that is kept up to date but otherwise only runs one low-privilege browser with few or no extensions and used to reach trusted sites only, will be about as safe as a Linux machine in the same situation.

Comment: It would also be wise to separate Windows and Linux across two HDDs/SSDs in my opinion - Windows is known to mess with dual boot systems.

Comment: Windows messes up dual boot systems if you install Windows after installing Linux. I have been running dual boot systems for two decades and Windows installing its own bootloader over Lilo/Grub/Grub2 was the only issue I ever had.

Comment: You actually can set the Windows bootloader to chainload GRUB if you want. If you don't, you run some risk (on MBR/BIOS systems) of Windows overwriting GRUB's first stage, though that's reparable with Linux boot media (just as the reverse issue is reparable with Windows boot media). With modern GPT disks and [U]EFI, you don't even have to worry about that anymore; Windows and Linux will both cheerfully install their bootloaders to the EFI System partition, and the firmware will let the user select which bootloader to load by default (and you can either override that per-boot, or chain-load).